# SMTPSenderRefused when sending email with Python logging

Tags: python

I'm using SMTPHandler to log my caught exceptions in my python script which requests new data to my backend.

Here's how I initialized my SMTPHandler:

```
# write errors to email
error_mail_subject = "ERROR: Script error in %s" % sys.argv[0]
error_mail_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=("smtp.gmail.com", 587),
                                                  fromaddr="test@gmail.com",
                                                  toaddrs="test@gmail.com",
                                                  subject=error_mail_subject)
error_mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
error_mail_handler.setFormatter(debug_format)

# Build the logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(error_mail_handler)
```

But unfortunately, I get this following error during handling of a script exception

```
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. w15sm3562054qta.16 - gsmtp', 'test@gmail.com')
```

When the script calls:

```
logger.exception(e)
```

Comment: Give your real Gmail address as sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This successfully sent an email from my gmail, tested just now:

```
import logging.handlers
error_mail_subject = "hello, it's me"
error_mail_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=("smtp.gmail.com", 587),
                                              fromaddr="email",
                                              toaddrs="email",                                                  
                                              subject=error_mail_subject,
                                              credentials=('email', 'password'),
                                              secure=())
error_mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(error_mail_handler)
logger.exception(Exception("hey"))
```

I also had to sign into gmail and then go here to allow access to less secure apps: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: You're the boss